# How to use more than one delay counter in same process in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Need implement multiple delay counter for following wait for clock cycle, synthesizable.

```
    if(clk'event and clk='1')then           
           if (StartTX = 1)then
                    TxBusy <= '1';
                    StartTxp <= '1';
                    Wait for 1 clock cycles;
                    StartTxp <= '0';
           End IF;

           IF (StartTX = 1)then
                    Wait x clock cycles  ;
                    StartTxM <= '1';
                    Wait 1 clock cycles;
                    StartTxM<= '0';
           End IF ;  

           IF (StartCal = 1) AND (StartInut =1 ) AND (IValid = 1)then
                    Wait 78 ns   ;
                   Interrupt <= '1'   ;  
                    Wait 1 clock cycle
                    Interrupt = 0
           End IF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can react on state change events of the control signal as starting point. example:

```
if(clk'event and clk='1')then 
      StartTx_Last<=StartTx; -- 1 clock cycle delayed copy of control signal
      StartTxp <= '0'; -- default value

       if (StartTX = 1 AND StartTx_Last=0) then -- activate signals only for one clock
                TxBusy <= '1';
                StartTxp <= '1';
                DelayCounter <= X; -- start delay counter
       End IF;

       -- set StartTxM after X clocks for 1 cycle
       case DelayCounter is
       when 1 => -- activity state
          StartTxM <= '1';
          DelayCounter<=0;
       when 0 => -- idle state
           StartTxM <='0';
       when others => -- delay states
          DelayCounter<=DelayCounter - 1;
       end case;
       ....
```

for the 78ns delay you need a clock with a period t and a n-counter where n*t=78ns

Comment: In second if statement, if starttx=1 then wait for X clock cycle. and then wait for 1 clock cycle for StattxM=1

Comment: that's what's happening in the example above... on StartTx=1, DelayCounter is initialized with X. as soon as the DelayCounter is decremented downto 1, StartTxM is set for 1 clock. DelayCounter stays 0 until next StartTx=1

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite as three separate state machines. These can be combined into one process if you must, but one process for each is probably simpler and clearer.

Use a counter for "wait X cycles" : load it with X in the idle state when you see StartTX; decrement it while in the wait state, and transition back to the idle state when it reaches 0.

Translate 78ns into an appropriate number of cycles for the third state machine, and implement it the same way as the second.

Comment: ok when you say one process for each, you mean for each state machine process right? Also how to combine all state machine process together?